# How can I hide a specific region according to its url?

Tags: theming

I need to hide the footer region on all pages with whose URL contains */people/*, similarly to what is possible to do with blocks.

Comment: The Context module can do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use hook_preprocess_page() hook (.modue/.theme file) to hide footer region conditionally:

```
function Mymodulename_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  $vars['display_footer_region'] = true;
  $current_path = \Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath();
  $ex_string = '/people';
  // set the display_footer_region false conditionally
  if (strpos($current_path, $ex_string) !== false) {
    $vars['display_footer_region'] = false;
  }  
  
}
```

Then go to page.html.twig & add the footer region inside condition:

```
{% if display_footer_region == true %}
  {{ page.footer }}
{% endif %}
```

Make sure override the page.html.twig inside the custom theme

Comment: Can this hook be used from the .theme?

Comment: Yes you can add hook .in theme file as well like this:
  Mythemename_preprocess_page(&$vars)